# can I use VirtualScrollStrategy for flex box with wrapping

Tags: angular-material

I have implemented Angular Material's virtual scrolling for fixed sized items. Now I want to use it with non-fixed items. The challenge is twofold:

1. The items contain a text that is wrapping around multiple lines. Thus, the height of an item depends on (a) the length of the text and (b) the width of the item's container. The latter depends on the width of the browser window.
2. The items are displayed in a flex box in wrap-around mode. Thus, there are multiple items in each row, the number depending on the width of the browser viewport.

My question is: Can that be achieved by implementing a custom VirtualScrollStrategy? If so, how would I approach it? Are there examples anywhere?